# Universal Clipboard doesn't work anymore

Tags: copy-paste

First time I've installed Sierra a couple of months ago, I tried the universal clipboard with my iPhone 6. It worked immediately like a charm and since I used it, I found this feature really useful for many use-cases.

Unfortunately, this feature doesn't work anymore after I upgraded from a 2 year old iPhone 6 to a new iPhone 7 Plus.

I know what I need for that feature to work (as it used to work fine):

- Both devices are connected with my iCloud account (same Apple ID)
- Bluetooth and Wifi are turned ON on both devices
- Both devices are connected to the same Wifi network
- Both devices are next to each other (less than 1 meter).
- iMAC 10.12.3 (16D32)
- iPhone 7 IOS 10.3

Both iMac and iPhone have been rebooted a couple of times.

No text, no URL, no picture can be copied & pasted from one device to the other anymore.

Any thought what could be wrong with the new iPhone 7?

Comment: Do all devices have have Handoff (continuity) turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn **continuity** (=handoff) on for both devices, and also make sure they are logged into **the same iCloud account**.

[Relevant documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) on Apple's website.

Comment: Thank you, Handoff was off on the iPhone. It's working back like a charm. yves

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! I would appreciate if you could accept my answer then :)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to describe how to turn on continuity?