# Universal Clipboard - Copying and pasting text from MacBook to iPhone not working anymore

Tags: iphone, copy-paste

I could always copy and paste texts from my **iPhone XS** to my **MacBook Pro 2019** or from my MacBook to my iPhone.

But today, while I can still copy and past texts from the iPhone to the MacBook, I cannot copy and paste from the MacBook to the iPhone any more.

Both devices are connected to the same Wifi and are logged in to the same Apple account.
I even rebooted both of them and it didn't help.

Any help?

Comment: Which versions of macOS and iOS are you using?

Comment: Might the solution in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278963/universal-clipboard-doesnt-work-anymore?rq=1) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, Universal Clipboard has always been a flakey feature.  It works about 50% of the time for me.  I don't think there's anything you can do to 'fix' it and it looks like you're already meeting the requirements, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth to try this:

1. Open your Terminal
2. Check if `ClipboardSharingEnabled` equals zero

   ```
    defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist ClipboardSharingEnabled
   ```
3. Set `ClipboardSharingEnabled` to 1

   ```
    defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist ClipboardSharingEnabled 1
   ```